# Update macro to expand each row height by X pixels

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, office365

This works fine to set all rows to 25 pixels.

```
Sub sbChangeRowHeightMulti()
Rows("3:1000").RowHeight = 25
End Sub
```

But I want to take the existing row height and add 10 to it.

So something like this pseudocode:

```
Sub sbChangeRowHeightMulti()
Rows("3:1000").RowHeight = Rows(x).RowHeight + 10
End Sub
```

Is that possible?  Been trying to figure out the syntax for it, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no simple one statement way to do this. Just as in Excel itself there is no way to select multiple rows and drag/set the row height to an increment of the individual heights.

The simplest solution is to loop over all the rows:

```
Option Explicit
'v0.1.0
Sub sbChangeRowHeightMulti()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim rowRow As Range
    For Each rowRow In Rows("3:1000")
      rowRow.RowHeight = rowRow.RowHeight + 10
    Next rowRow
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but Office Scripts seems more accessible than VBA macros so here is an alternative to the accepted answer.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  
  /**Change padding amount below*/
  let padding = 10;
  
  let worksheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
  let usedRange = worksheet.getUsedRange();
  let cnt = usedRange.getRowCount();
  for (var row = 0; row < cnt; row++) {
    usedRange.getRow(row).getFormat().setRowHeight(usedRange.getRow(row).getFormat().getRowHeight() + padding);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
Sub sbChangeRowHeightMulti()
Rows("3:1000").RowHeight = Rows("3:1000").RowHeight + 10
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you do something special to get this to work?  It doesn’t work for me.   Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @Scott Resonding in comments because I have nothing to add to my answer at this point: Perhaps I misunderstood the question. I did not do anything special to get it to work. It adds 10 to the existing row height of the designated rows. Was that not the original question?

Comment: (1) I think we agree on the meaning of the question (although your statement of it is a little imprecise, so I’m not sure you and I are thinking the same thing). (2) I’m a little confused.  I thought that, when I tested your answer yesterday, it did nothing.  I’ve retested it, and it definitely does something, so I guess (at best) I was sloppy yesterday. (3) What your answer seems to do is compute `Rows("3").RowHeight + 10` and set the height of every row to that value.  I believe that the question is asking to add a constant to the height of each row,  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  so if the current heights are 15, 21, 27, 33, …, they would be changed to 25, 31, 37, 43, ….   (Rereading the question, I concede that it’s unclear; but note that [robinCTS](https://superuser.com/q/1334180/150988#1334201) interpreted it the same way I did.)   Your answer would change them to 25, 25, 25, 25, …. (4) You’ve obviously noticed that somebody down voted your answer.   It wasn’t I.  So somebody other than me believes that your answer is wrong.